# Converting Integer To Hex Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need for my app this int[] format as I wrote in the title.

I'm fetching the value out of a `HashMap` which is filled out of an XML file with this format [00, 00, 00, 00], but I need it for every `int` with `0x`in front.

I tried to "convert" it via a for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
        value[i] = "0x"  + value[i];
    }
```

but I cant convert from `String` to `int` this way.

Then I tried to change it directly in the XML file, but then my app crashes with an NPE.

Now I want to know if there is a solution to my problem.

**EDIT:**

For further explanation:

I tried this before, but it did not work:

```
public int[] getValue(Map map, String key) {
    Map keyMap = map;
    int[] value = {};

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Iterator iter = keyMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
        if (mEntry.getKey().equals(key)) {
            value = (int[]) mEntry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Then I tried one of the answers and added

```
for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
        value[i] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(value[i]), 16);
    }
```

before the return. Now it works... but I dont know why it works :(

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for "java converting integer to string"?

Comment: I dont want a string, I want it like this: `int[] int = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}`

Comment: That's not possible, because `int` is `int` - hexadecimal prefixes are only for interpretation and not for calculation.

Comment: but if I insert it by hand it works

Comment: Yes, as I said - for interpretation purposes, but stored as `int`.

Comment: There is no difference between `int[] a = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}` and `int[] a = {0,0,0,0}`

Comment: hm... but why does it not work as I want? only when I got it with the `0x` it works ... without it doesn't

Comment: see my edit above. Maybe it didn't not work because it was not proper converted into an hex int ?

Comment: I doubt that `value[i] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(value[i]), 16);` works in general. The problem is that you already have a wrong value when you read the XML, sometimes even a `NumberFormatException`. You cannot repair that after the fact.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, so I fixed the issue in my `XmlPullParser` and now I don't even need my `getValue()` method. Thx for mentioning that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any typed language int/number values have no format. The way Java stores int values is as 4 byte number using Two's complement, so 0 or 0x0 or 00 (octal) or 0b is the same value: 32 zeros in a binary word.

SECOND EDIT:

I think you are over-engineering. What you should use is a

```
Map<String,int[]> map;
```

then, if you write map.get(key), you'll obtain what you're looking for.

NEW EXPLANATION: The previous solution worked because when you read the XML stored the values as decimal ones:

```
String s="80";
int i= Integer.valueOf(s); //it stores 80 (decimal value)
int value= Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(i),16); //It stores 128, or 0x80 (hex value)
```

Comment: the key is just a String to better identify the value stored to it (for better reading purposes)

Comment: okay, the `String.valueOf()` was part of an answer which is now deleted (dont know why he deleted it). hm... as I now tried to delete the String.valueOf part, it does say `The method valueOf(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)`

Comment: Yes, I was messing myself... let me try to understand again what you need :P

Comment: The problem I had was that converted a String out of an XML. String is `80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`. So through a XmlPullparser I fetched the data and stored it in a HashMap. Now I wanted to take via a key the value stored to it. So I fetched it and saved it to the `value` int array. The Problem why it did not work was, that in my pullparser I didnt convert it correctly to an hex int. But at the moment it works with the answer that was posted, but which is now deleted

Comment: to your edit: Yeah, that was what I was supposed to do, but that didn't work so I tried it the way I posted. Maybe I'll try to change the code, because now I think I got the mistake in the PullParser, where the conversion takes place.

Comment: @Fraggles Correct, the parsing must be done when reading the XML, using Integer.valueOf(mystring,16) to store the correct integer. You were storing decimal values, that's why you needed to re-evaluate them

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, just didnt recognized it :) Thx for your help :) I'll mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
    value[i] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(value[i]), 16);
}
```

Try this. If you want the hex value. Or in case if you want hex string you can use below code.

```
Integer.toHexString(integerValue)
```

Comment: did not get that can you explain further ?

Comment: See my answer for more details